# Problem with making textbox value to save after page refresh: All textbox values became the same

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, event-handling

I am trying to make it so my textbox input saves after being changed even after page refresh. I successfully made it to work but discovered a few problems.

- All my other input textbox now also have the same new stored value once I change one.

This is because I had put the `id` element of all my textbox inputs for this section of my website the same. I just discovered that this is bad so I am trying to find a fix.

However, if I change all the `id`s uniquely, how do I make them all store their own modified user inputs without having to re-write the same function code for each `id` textbox?

Here is my code so far:

Event handling:

```
//store value after changes
function store(){
    var nb = this.value;
    localStorage.setItem("qty",nb);
}
//local storage to keep values after refresh
function getValue(){
    var storeNb = localStorage.getItem("qty");

    if(storedText != null){
        document.getElementById("qty").value = storedNb; 
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("qty").value = 0;
}
```

Event registering:

```
document.getElementById("qty").oninput = store; //stores new values to localstorage upon changes
document.getElementById("qty").onload = getValue(); //gets value from localstorage upon page load
```

HTML (all the inputs are like thus, one per webpage):

```
<input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" class="small">
```

Comment: Give each item the same class and use the `id` as a parameter for the two functions

Comment: Pls share the html code your are concerned with, to get a better picture

Comment: @aprouja1 How would I retrieve the value for each textbox when I load the page?